# Web scraping with request do not get the data of the website

Tags: web-scraping, request

I am trying to do web scraping to get the data of the tables of this web.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0144861722004441?via%3Dihub

However, when I do:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla Firefox 99.0.1'}
url = "https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0144861722004441"
data = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text  # I also tried with: data = requests.get(url, headers = headers).content
print(data)
```

I get an output for *data* that does not even correspond with the content of the web...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: From their [Tos](https://www.elsevier.com/legal/elsevier-website-terms-and-conditions): *"You may not use any robots, spiders, crawlers or other automated downloading programs, algorithms or devices, or any similar or equivalent manual process, to: (i) continuously and automatically search, scrape, extract, deep link or index any Content;.."*

Comment: Thank you. I don´t really understand this limitation for open source articles like this. So I guess the only option is to download the PDF and do data extraction from it then.

Comment: This is mostly addressing the issue of ads: Scraping bots don't view ads and don't click on ads but they generate page impressions and thus skew ad metrics.